# REST API vs Websocket for buying an asset

Tags: python, rest, websocket, binance, binance-api-client

I have confusion between Rest API and Websocket. Although WS is faster than REST API in terms of data fetching. My application is to Buy a Coin(any item) on any Exchange (Binance, Kucoin, Coinbase) as fast as I can. In the documentations, Every exchange provides Endpoints for order place(Buying the coin) only for REST API. They only provide a Coin price stream for Websockets.
Is it Possible to Buy or post something using Websockets or do we have to use REST API for that Purpose?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you need websocket to place an order, even if you are developing a trading bot, placing an order will not happen a lot.
so i suggest you use REST API

also, i think the only useful way to have websocket, is to get K lines.